# Download Embedded PDF File

Tags: excel, vba

**Question**: How do I download a PDF file which is embedded in Excel?

This question has been asked so many times but I have not seen a single working answer anywhere.

So here is an attempt to self answer the question. This code works and is not dependent on the unreliable `.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary` method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note: This will only work for pdf files. If there is a mix of embedded files then this will not work.

**Basic Preparations:**

1. Let's say our Excel File `C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sample.xlsx` has 2 Pdf Files embedded as shown below.

   [image]
2. For testing purpose, we will create a temp folder on our desktop `C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Temp`.

**Logic:**

1. The Excel file is essentially just a .zip file
2. Excel saves the `oleObjects` in the `\xl\embeddings\` folder. If you rename the Excel file to zip and open it in say Winzip, you can see the following

   [image]
3. If you extract the bin files and rename it to pdf then you will be able to open the pdf in `Microsoft Edge` but not in any other pdf viewer. To make it compatible with any other pdf viewer, we will have to do some `Binary` reading and editing.
4. If you open the bin file in any Hex Editor, you will see the below. I used the online hex editor https://hexed.it/

   [image]

   We have to delete everything before the word `%PDF`

   We will try and find the 8 bit unsigned values of `%PDF`... Or more specifically of `%`, `P`, `D` and `F`

   If you scroll down in the hex editor, you will get those four values

   *Value of `%`*
   [image]

   *Value of `P`*
   [image]

   *Value of `D`*
   [image]

   *Value of `F`*
   [image]

   Now all we have to do is read the binary file and delete everything before `%PDF` and save the file with a `.Pdf` extention.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Const TmpPath As String = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Temp"
Const ExcelFile As String = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sample.xlsx"
Const ZipName As String = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sample.zip"

Sub ExtractPDF()
    Dim tmpPdf As String
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Deleting any previously created files. This is
    '~~> usually helpful from 2nd run onwards
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill ZipName
    Kill TmpPath & "\*.*"
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Copy and rename the Excel file as zip file
    FileCopy ExcelFile, ZipName

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    '~~> Extract the bin file from xl\embeddings\
    For i = 1 To oApp.Namespace(ZipName).items.Count
        oApp.Namespace(TmpPath).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(ZipName).items.Item("xl\embeddings\oleObject" & i & ".bin")

        tmpPdf = TmpPath & "\oleObject" & i & ".bin"

        '~~> Read and Edit the Bin File
        If Dir(tmpPdf) <> "" Then ReadAndWriteExtractedBinFile tmpPdf
    Next i

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

'~~> Read and ReWrite Bin File
Sub ReadAndWriteExtractedBinFile(s As String)
    Dim intFileNum As Long, bytTemp As Byte
    Dim MyAr() As Long, NewAr() As Long
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    j = 1

    intFileNum = FreeFile

    '~~> Open the bing file
    Open s For Binary Access Read As intFileNum
    '~~> Get the number of lines in the bin file
    Do While Not EOF(intFileNum)
        Get intFileNum, , bytTemp
        j = j + 1
    Loop

    '~~> Create an array to store the filtered results of the bin file
    '~~> We will use this to recreate the bin file
    ReDim MyAr(1 To j)
    j = 1

    '~~> Go to first record
    If EOF(intFileNum) Then Seek intFileNum, 1

    '~~> Store the contents of bin file in an array
    Do While Not EOF(intFileNum)
        Get intFileNum, , bytTemp
        MyAr(j) = bytTemp
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    Close intFileNum

    '~~> Check for the #PDF and Filter out rest of the data
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        If i = UBound(MyAr) - 4 Then Exit For
        If Val(MyAr(i)) = 37 And Val(MyAr(i + 1)) = 80 And _
        Val(MyAr(i + 2)) = 68 And Val(MyAr(i + 3)) = 70 Then
            ReDim NewAr(1 To j - i + 2)

            k = 1
            For j = i To UBound(MyAr)
                NewAr(k) = MyAr(j)
                k = k + 1
            Next j

            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    intFileNum = FreeFile

    '~~> Decide on the new name of the pdf file
    '~~> Format(Now, "ddmmyyhhmmss")  This method will awlays ensure that
    '~~> you will get a unique filename
    fileName = TmpPath & "\" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyhhmmss") & ".pdf"

    '~~> Write the new binary file
    Open fileName For Binary Lock Read Write As #intFileNum
    For i = LBound(NewAr) To UBound(NewAr)
        Put #intFileNum, , CByte(NewAr(i))
    Next i

    Close #intFileNum
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I second that +

Comment: Surely `Dim MyAr() As Long, NewAr() As Long` should be declared as Byte arrays?  Also, the NewAr() Byte array can be `Put` in its entirety, without looping through its members.

Comment: True. By default, my fingers when I type, ignore, byte, integer etc :P They like `Long`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout thanks a lot for this masterpiece. Is there a way to extract all the images from PDF file?

Comment: @YasserKhalil without using adobe pro, I doubt it...

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have the adobe acrobat pro. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @YasserKhalil: I can try and help but really tied up with lot of work. This is the reason I post less now a days. BTW have you seen [THIS](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?877645-Extracting-Images-from-A-PDF-file-Revisit) or [THIS](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/how-to-extract-images-from-pdf-page-by-page-in-visual-basic-6-and-VBScript+)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest. Take your time and if you found some time, you can post an answer. Will I open new thread or leave it till you are ready :) ?

Comment: As for the first link you posted and in the post #13 I have tried yesterday and I found it difficult to put this line `imgstrt = "ÿØÿ"` in my code .. and I am not sure if it will succeed or not.

Comment: As for the second link, it work on VBScript and I couldn't convert to VBA. So I post the problem yesterday at the link  http://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=35652

Comment: @YasserKhalil I jus tested [THIS](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?877645-Extracting-Images-from-A-PDF-file-Revisit&p=5409697&viewfull=1#post5409697) and it works just fine. Tested with this [PDF](http://wikisend.com/download/550602/Test.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a problem at inserting this line in my code `imgstrt = "ÿØÿ"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224311/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-yasserkhalil). @YasserKhalil

Comment: With only slight modifications for my scripts...this works great!!! Thanks!