# Excel Object: Impossible to open an embedded object

Tags: excel, vba, embedded-object

I'm new and have a question. Hoping that someone can help. I have received an Excel Document with embedded PDF Objects (first picture).

Embedded Adobe Acrobat PDF:

[image]

I can't open it, because Acrobat Reader isn't installed and i have not the rights to install software.

Error message in German:

[image]

I want to change the related program to pdf-xchange editor. Can anyone give me suggestions how to do that?

Embedded pdf which is working:

[image]

By the way: pdf-xchange editor is not listed in the object type list.

Object list:

[image]

I don't want to save them on disc, just have the possibility to permanently open them, when I need it.

I hope you understand my Problem. Thanks in advance.

Patrik

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sure, that it is not just a linked file. The standard viewer should open the PDF. I agree with you. But it doesn't work. Maybe because the PDF-type is not in the object-type-list? Double click on a PDF-document in the file explorer opens the PDF-Xchange program. Its the standard viewer in Windows. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you actually save it to disk? Not, sure but I think you can't (at least not with built in methods). And I'm pretty sure you cannot change the program "related". Also see: [Download Embedded PDF File In Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778729/download-embedded-pdf-file-in-excel)

Comment: Too bad there's no solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think there _is_ a solution: use the code linked by Peh to save a temporary copy, open it, and when done delete it.  May not be your ideal solution,  but it is _a_ solution

Comment: I understand, and i will give it a try. But the document should be usable not only for me and not only one time - i have to build a new document with lots of embedded PDFs. Thanks again.

Comment: I have saved the files as described in the link. It's even easier than described, after saving, they can be opened immediately with pdf-exchange, without further editing. But in my specific case there are 170 files, which I would have to assign and reload all manually. This is almost impossible, because the name has nothing to do with the original name. All are called oleObjectnnn.pdf. So this is no solution for me, unless you can use the "real" name for saving. Thanks.