# Save an embedded file to a location (export file from excel) with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a little macro, that opens a Form where you can input details,
when you click on a button, you create a list with all the entries and save a selected pdf file thats embedded on another worksheet.
The Code works when you dont embed it as symbol. It basically creates a "screenshot" with the pdf. But i simply want to save the embedded object in a fixed path
`

```
Sub Schaltfläche6_Klicken()
Dim saveLocation As String
Dim sFolderPath As String

UserForm1.Show

sFolderPath = "C:\test\Excel"
saveLocation = "C:\test\Excel\Dummy.pdf"

If Dir(sFolderPath) <> "" Then
    MkDir "C:\test\Excel"
End If


Worksheets("Dummy").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=saveLocation
End Sub
```

`

Hope you have a solution for the problem

i tried to find some solutions on the internet, but it didnt really helped. It looked a bit too complicated for what i really want

Comment: It is a confusing question, It seems your code is working. Do you want a RANGE to be exported only?

Comment: It is not so simple as you look wanting... It is a security issue, to not be able saving an embedded virus, for instance. But, theoretically, it can be done in three ways. The simplest (code) needs `Adobe Acrobat` (**Not Reader**), the code will open the embedded pdf file in it and then save using its COM interface and its method. The second onw would be using API to catch the default application window handler, and manipulate it. The third does not need that, it will extract the embedded files from the `bin` ones in the zipped workbook file, modifying its binary code. Complicated, but working

Comment: Is the workbook keeping the embedded pdf files of `xlsm` type? If more than such an embedded file, based on what to build the saved pdf name?

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the next scenario. It cannot be a simple one, as I tried suggesting in my above comment:

1. Embed the pdf files but use 'Alt Text' to place there the pdf file name. It can be manually add by right clicking on the OLE object - `Format Object...` - `Alt Text` or in code, if you embed the files in this way. I can supply a code modification for such a case, if needed.
2. The workbook where from to be embedded pdf files extracted (WBPdf), must be closed.
3. Since, as stated above, WBPdf should be closed, the next code must be copied in a `xlsm` file and run it from there. Basically, it saves a copy of WBPdf with zip extension (in fact workbook type xlsx, xlsm, xlsa etc. are such archives containing many `xml` files and objects. The code firstly extracts the files from archive `\xl\worksheets`, processes them to extract a logical association between the `bin` files in `\xl\embeddings` and the pdf name extracted from worksheets `xml` files. Then, it binary open the found `bin` files, and process them to become correct pdf files. I placed a link to an answer where this process has very well explained some years before:

a. Create a `Public` variable on top of a standard module (in the declarations area):

```
   Public ExpArr()
```

It will keep the correspondence between the `bin` file to pdf name to be saved as.

b. Copy the next code in a standard module:

```
Sub ExtractEmbeddedPDFs() 'it does NOT work if the workbook to be processed is Open!
    Dim pdfFolder As String, embWB As String, zipName As String, oShell As Object, arrO, i As Long
    
    pdfFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Extracted PDF"
    embWB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Embedded pdf.xlsx"
    zipName = left(embWB, InStrRev(embWB, ".")) & "zip"
     
     If Dir(pdfFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then 'if the folder where to save pdf files does not exist
        MkDir pdfFolder                                      'it is created
     End If


    'Deleting any previously created files, if any:
    On Error Resume Next
      Kill zipName
      Kill pdfFolder & "\*.*"
      Kill pdfFolder & "\_rels\*.*"
      RmDir pdfFolder & "\_rels\"
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Copy/rename the Excel file changing extension to zip:
    On Error Resume Next
       FileCopy embWB, zipName
       If err.Number = 70 Then        'error in case of workbook being open:
            err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
            MsgBox "Please, close the workbook where from the embedded pdf files should be extracted." & vbCrLf & _
                           "A zipped copy cannot be created...", vbInformation, "Need to close the workbook": Exit Sub
       End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim flsWsh As Object, fileNameInZip As Variant
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    Set flsWsh = oShell.NameSpace(oShell.NameSpace((zipName)).Items.Item(("xl\worksheets")))
    For Each fileNameInZip In oShell.NameSpace(flsWsh).Items
            oShell.NameSpace((pdfFolder)).CopyHere _
                    oShell.NameSpace(flsWsh).Items.Item(CStr(fileNameInZip))
    Next
    
    getOLEObjSheetsREL pdfFolder 'build the array which matches any .bin oleObject with the extracted pdf name
   
    For i = 0 To UBound(ExpArr)
        arrO = Split(ExpArr(i), "|") 'split the matching array elements by "|" to extract bin name in relation with pdf name
        oShell.NameSpace((pdfFolder)).CopyHere oShell.NameSpace((zipName)).Items.Item("xl\embeddings\" & arrO(0))
        
        ReadAndWriteExtractedBinFile pdfFolder & "\" & arrO(0), pdfFolder, CStr(arrO(1))
    Next i
    
    On Error Resume Next
      Kill zipName
      Kill pdfFolder & "\*.bin"
      Kill pdfFolder & "\*.xml"
      Kill pdfFolder & "\_rels\*.*"
      RmDir pdfFolder & "\_rels\"
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    MsgBox "Ready..."
    Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & pdfFolder, vbNormalFocus 'open the folder keeping extracted files
End Sub

'Eliminate specific characters from binary file to make it pdf compatible:
'see here a good process explanation:
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778729/download-embedded-pdf-file
Sub ReadAndWriteExtractedBinFile(s As String, TmpPath, Optional pdfName As String = "")
    Dim byteFile As Long, byt As Byte, fileName As String
    Dim MyAr() As Byte, NewAr() As Byte, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    byteFile = FreeFile:  j = 1

    Open s For Binary Access Read As byteFile 'Open the bin file
        Do While Not EOF(byteFile) 'loop untill the last line (count the file bytes)
            Get byteFile, , byt:  j = j + 1
        Loop

        'create the (correct) pdf byte file, removing some bytes (characters) from the bin byte one:___
        ReDim MyAr(1 To j - 1) 'initially reDim it to have the same dimension as byteFile
        j = 1
    
        If EOF(byteFile) Then Seek byteFile, 1 'set first byte position for the next iteration
    
        Do While Not EOF(byteFile) 'place the content of bin byteFile in MyAr:
            Get byteFile, , byt
            MyAr(j) = byt:  j = j + 1
        Loop
    Close byteFile
    
    'build the correct byte array without bytes existing up to %PDF:
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        If i = UBound(MyAr) - 4 Then Exit For  'eliminate the not necessary last 4 bytes
        If val(MyAr(i)) = 37 And val(MyAr(i + 1)) = 80 And _
              val(MyAr(i + 2)) = 68 And val(MyAr(i + 3)) = 70 Then 'when find %PDF
            ReDim NewAr(1 To j - i + 1)                                            'reDim the array to eliminate everything before it
            k = 1
            For j = i To UBound(MyAr)
                NewAr(k) = MyAr(j):  k = k + 1
            Next j
            Exit For  'exits the loop (after finding %PDF bytes)
        End If
    Next i

    byteFile = FreeFile

    'Set the pdf to be saved name:
    If pdfName = "" Then 'if no pdfName parameter, it builds a unique name:
        fileName = TmpPath & "\" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyhhmmss") & ".pdf"
    Else
       fileName = TmpPath & "\" & pdfName  'this solution uses only the extracted (from OLEObject) name
    End If
    'Write the new (pdf) binary file:
    If isArrLoaded(NewAr()) Then 'only for PDF (bin) embedded files:
        Open fileName For Binary Lock Read Write As #byteFile
            For i = LBound(NewAr) To UBound(NewAr)
                Put #byteFile, , CByte(NewAr(i))
            Next i
        Close #byteFile
    Else
        'If by mistake a not appropriate bin file has been choosen:
        Debug.Print "The object is not of pdf type..." 'theoretically, this line should never be reached
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub getOLEObjSheetsREL(strPath As String)
   Dim patt As String: patt = "oleObject\d{1,3}.bin"
   Dim strFold As String, strFile As String, strText As String
   Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, arrOLE, arrOLEC(1), arrTot, i As Long
   
   strFold = strPath & "\_rels\" 'copied folder (from archive) keeping sheets keeping OLEObjects
   
   ReDim arrTot(0)
   strFile = Dir(strFold & "*.rels")
   Do While strFile <> "" 'iterate between all existing files
         Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
         Set ts = fso.getFile(strFold & strFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
              strText = ts.ReadAll  'read their content
         ts.Close
         arrOLE = getOLEObj(strText, patt) 'extract an array linking OLEObject to pdf file name
         
         If arrOLE(0) <> "" Then
            arrOLEC(0) = left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 5): arrOLEC(1) = arrOLE
            BubbleSort arrOLEC(1) 'sort the array
            arrTot(i) = arrOLEC: i = i + 1: ReDim Preserve arrTot(i)
         End If
         strFile = Dir()
    Loop
    ReDim Preserve arrTot(i - 1)
    getOLEObjects arrTot, strPath 'returning an array linking the bin object to pdf to be saved file  name
End Sub

Private Sub BubbleSort(arr)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i) > arr(j) Then
                temp = arr(i): arr(i) = arr(j)
                arr(j) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub


Private Sub getOLEObjects(arrOLE As Variant, strPath As String)
   Dim strFile As String, strText As String
   Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, j As Long
   Dim arr, frstTxt As String, El, i As Long, strName As String, PrID As String
   Dim k As Long: ReDim ExpArr(100)
   Const strObj As String = "oleObject"
   
   For j = 0 To UBound(arrOLE)
         strFile = strPath & "\" & arrOLE(j)(0)
         Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
         Set ts = fso.getFile(strFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
              strText = ts.ReadAll
        ts.Close
        
        arr = extractBetweenChars(strText, "<oleObject progId=", "<\/mc:Fallback>")
          
        For Each El In arr
              strName = "": PrID = ""
              strName = extractBetweenChars(CStr(El), "altText=""", """ r:id")(0)
              PrID = extractBetweenChars(CStr(El), """", """")(0)

              If PrID = "Acrobat Document" Or PrID = "Packager Shell Object" Then i = i + 1
              If strName <> "" Then
                   If InStr(strName, ".pdf") > 0 Then
                          ExpArr(k) = strObj & i & ".bin" & "|" & strName: k = k + 1
                   End If
              End If
        Next
  Next j
  
  'keep only the elements keeping values:
  If k > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve ExpArr(k - 1)
  Else
       Erase ExpArr
 End If
End Sub
```

The workbook keeping embedded pdf files, can also contain embedded csv, xls, txt, jpg files. The code is able to distinguish between them and use for extraction only the appropriate `bin` files.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: @Polarus Didn't you still find some time to test the above suggested solution? **I did it for you, I do not need it**... If tested, didn't it do what you need? The "complicate" aspect is not in issue, I would say. You should only copy the code and use it. Even if you do not want understanding...